# Spring Data autowire the repository interfaces directly

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data and I would like to know if it is correct to autowire the repositories direcly this way (supposing no more methods are needed) since Spring 4 can solve generic autowiring:

```
@Autowired
CrudRepository<User,Long> repo;
```

There is more than one bean that implements this interface (SimpleJPARepository, QueryDslJpaRepository) so Spring couldn't solve the autowiring isn't it?

But when if you do:

```
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<User,Long> () {
}
```

What bean autowire for the implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can autowire `CrudRepository<User,Long> repo;` directly, I guess that could work. Try it.

Usually you declare that you want to have a repository for `User` by defining an interface like

```
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<User,Long> () {
}
```

and then you simply autowire it. (I would also suggest you name it `UserRespository` because that's what it's job is)

```
@Autowired
MyRepo repo;
```

The magic trick is that Spring Data then implements the interface for you. You get that implementation autowired and your code stays clean of implementation details of the database you use.

> There is more than one bean that implements this interface (SimpleJPARepository, QueryDslJpaRepository) so Spring couldn't solve the autowiring isn't it?

It has to do that in the regular case as well. There are rules & configuration somewhere that will decide which implementation to pick in case it has more than 1 candidate for the interface you want.

In case of `SimpleJPARepository` vs `QueryDslJpaRepository` it probably boils down to whether you use the extra features or not. The documentation of the latter is

> QueryDsl specific extension of SimpleJpaRepository which adds implementation for QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

If you don't want a type that inherits `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` it doesn't need to base the magic implementation on that class.

Comment: I guess the question here is not being able to do, but it's about good practices. MVC Pattern consists in separate the layers, if your DAO works with MySQL, MSSQL or WhateverQL, the other layers shouldn't know about it, simply because it doesn't matter to them. Having an Abstract Generic Class which can persist, select and update generic objects, and an interface to declare the methods, is good practice.
+1 for your good explanation about `Usually you declare that you want to have a repository for User`

Comment: In fact `CrudRepository<User,Long> repo` can't be solved, I guess because Spring Data JPA was build before Spring generic classes supporting, so the interface must be implemented.

Comment: @EstebanS hm, seems to be possible to autowire correct generic types even with type erasure. So that could be it.