# How does spring boot initialise repository

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long>{
    Room findByNumber(String number);
}
```

I have the RoomRepository above

```
@Service
public class ReservationService {
    private RoomRepository roomRepository;
    private GuestRepository guestRepository;
    private ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ReservationService(RoomRepository roomRepository, GuestRepository guestRepository, ReservationRepository reservationRepository) {
        this.roomRepository = roomRepository;
        this.guestRepository = guestRepository;
        this.reservationRepository = reservationRepository;
    }
```

My service class is shown above. Why can spring initialize an interface? Thank you

Comment: Probably you can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999879/spring-data-autowire-the-repository-interfaces-directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are Spring Data repositories actually implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented)

Answer (score 0):

Spring is creating a proxy for the interface, the proxy delegates all calls to an already existing implementation. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509882/how-are-spring-data-repositories-actually-implemented) contains an excellent explanation